# blazor server side refresh page contents after reload of model

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using a server side blazor page to render contents of a model similar to this

```
EntityModelData
      int Id;
      string Name;
      List<ValueEntry> Values;


    <div>@model.Name</div>
    <div>@model.Property2</div>
    <div>@model.Property3</div>
    <ul>
    @foreach (var item in model.Values)
    {
      <li>
        @item   //On click call EditValue and provide an option to modify the list item 
        //After submission of edit the StateHasChanged() and reload of model occured , but UI is not refreshing 
      </li>
    }
    </ul>


[Parameter]
public int DbEntryId { get; set; }

private EntityModelData model;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    model = await SettingsService.GetDbEntryById(DbEntryId);
}

async async void EditValue()
{
    ValueEntry valModel = new ValueEntry();
    valModel.prop1=..;
    valModel.prop2=..;
    valModel.prop3=..;.....
  
    bool entryStatus = await SettingsService.UpdateValue(DbEntryId,valModel);
    
    if(entryStatus) //data inserted without error 
    {
      //reload model
      model = await SettingsService.GetDbEntryById(DbEntryId);
      StateHasChanged(); //BUT NO CHANGES VISIBLE IN UI 
    }
    
}
```

on page init the model is populated from database and values are appearing correctly . when adding a new items to the Values property the UI is getting reload without refreshing the page ,
But after making an edit on the Value entry i am repopulating the model from database but the page contents are not reloading or getting updated

Comment: what happens if async void is changed to async Task?

Comment: @Frank  no difference. Still UI Is not getting updated , If i reload page all looks good

Comment: Basically this shouldn't be happening but I was diving into Blazor recently and hit a similar problem that turned out to be my mishandling of async calls.... It would be good to see the code that calls the Edit on click and etc. You might want to try and make a dummy async Edit handler that just calls the API with a dummy change and set the Model property . StateHasChanged shouldn't be needed either

Comment: I agree with Frank.  You almost certainly have an un-awaited async method in your `SettingsService` that lets `EditValue` run to completion before `model` is updated.  Try setting `model` to null before calling `GetDbEntryById` and see if things fall over.

Comment: Every time i see `async void` I die a little..

Comment: I agree with the above discussion. It would be great if you post the entire code and edit to bring clarity to the code.